# DI Factory for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection, ninject

I'm looking for a way to inject dependency without calling Ninject's `Get` method.

For example in ASP.NET MVC I create a class that inherits from `DefaultControllerFactory`<sup>[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.defaultcontrollerfactory%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)</sup>, and  add it to the controller builder's factory with `ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory`<sup>[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbuilder.setcontrollerfactory%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)</sup>. Once I do that, I never call `Get`, and it fills in automatically.

**Is there an equivalent for WPF?**

I need a general answer that will fit most situations but if I have to give an example, I made a control in WPF,
However it has a parameter in the constructor:

```
public AppVolumeSlider(IVolumeSetter volumeSetter)
```

Since my controls are in markup, WPF complains, of course: `The type "AppVolumeSlider" does not include any accessible constructors.`.

How can I make Ninject/WPF fill it appropriately?

*Note 1: If I can't do it in this example (I guess because of the markup) please give me a general answer. For example if I just make a class with a similar constructor and not a control. I still need to know this information.*

*Note 2: I have a hunch this might be related to the `Inject` attribute, but I have no idea.*

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the various MVVM frameworks like Caliburn Micro: http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/ Most of them come with IoC container support.

Comment: Could you elaborate? how would they help me achieve my goal? I'd really appreciate an example or a reference to a guide if you have it.

Answer (score 0):

Some containers, like Unity have a function to provide dependencies to already existing instances. Of course this will not work for construcor injection. But it will work find for propery/method injection.

You can create your WPF Page (or whatever control), it will load markup, and then call Unity.BuildUp(your_object).

Or equivalent function of different container.